# Hyperlinks in power view not work

Tags: powerbi

hi I am trying to link files which are in my hard drive through power view in excel.
is anybody can help what steps to follow to link local files from power view.
thanks

Comment: You need to read about asking questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can't hyperlink to files or shares in Power View, only sites and email addresses. See [here](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Whats-new-in-Power-View-in-Excel-2013-and-in-SharePoint-Server-8e3b4259-421e-41fc-a48e-854388ad14d0?CorrelationId=7d557675-b55c-4287-86e8-8526c889b957&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US). Those hyperlinks can be in your data or can be added to text boxes.